# Syntax error with If statement

Tags: python, debugging

I'm just learning Python and right now i'm making a very simple rock, paper, scissors game where the user picks one choice and the computer randomly picks another then the program compares the two and says who won.
My code looks like this:

```
print ('Rock, Paper, Scissors! The game of random guessing!')
print (input('Please hit enter to begin'))
choice = input('Choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors: ')
print('You decided on: ', choice)

import random
'''random gives this program the ability to randomly choose from a list'''
ComputerChoiceOptions = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
ComputerChoice = random.choice(ComputerChoiceOptions)
print('The computer went with:', ComputerChoice)

if choice = ComputerChoice
Winner = 'Tie'
    Print(Winner)
```

My question is specifically with this bit

```
 if choice = ComputerChoice
```

My debugger gives me a syntax error with this and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Indention, lack of a colon, single `=` vs `==`

Comment: Your code is riddled with typos and mistakes. Please take more care when writing your code.

Comment: What kind of typos and mistakes? Everything but the line I mentioned runs fine. I take it out and things compile

Comment: Consider reading the python tutorials/documentation, and try understanding the error it gives you. They are remarkably easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statements (and other control blocks) require a colon and indentation. Also, test for equality by using a double '='.

Example:

```
if choice == ComputerChoice:
    assign = 0
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. You'll just end up throwing an error with that `return`. Had this been a function, this would've been the answer :)

Comment: Epic fail, didn't pay attention to the original code block, just the if.

Comment: Nah, it's good. We all copy paste :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! modified my code and this fixed it. Much more helpful than the people saying it was wrong but not why.

Comment: No problem, everyone starts somewhere. Just please keep in mind there are guidelines to asking questions and making your code as legible as possible is super important.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the question I'm assuming you are learning programming for the first time, as your problem is one of the first concepts any programmer must learn.

You need to use a `==` instead of a `=` when comparing two things in an if statement. When you use a `=` it assigns the item.

Also, since you are using Python, you will need to indent the body of the if statement.